# C# pass data between functions

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a code that will write the data coming from an external device (USB) to a file. I have a function that receives data in a separate task `ReadAvailable` and I don't know how to pass this data in a correct way to the `SaveRxDataToFile` function. The write function must also know how much data it is adding each time to the file in order to know when to end the write.
(I'm learning and maybe it's something simple, but I'm a little lost)

Could you please help?

Here is the code:

```
using FTD2XX_NET;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace Engine
{
    public class FtdiFifo
    {

        private FTDI ftHandle = new FTDI();
        private FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] deviceInfos = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[2];

        public byte[] RxDataBuffer { get; set; } = new byte[65536];

        public List<string> serialNumbers { get; set; }

        public FtdiFifo()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is a new FtdiFifo object.");
            serialNumbers = new List<string>();

        }

        public void IdentifyDevice()
        {
            FTDI.FT_STATUS ftdiStatus;
            uint ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
            serialNumbers.Clear();

            ftdiStatus = ftHandle.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
            if (ftdiDeviceCount > 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Number of FTDI devices: " + ftdiDeviceCount.ToString());
            }
            else if (ftdiDeviceCount == 0) // If no devices available, return
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No FTDI device detected (" + ftdiStatus.ToString() + ")");
                return;
            }


            ftdiStatus = ftHandle.GetDeviceList(deviceInfos);
            if (ftdiStatus == FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                for (UInt32 i = 0; i < ftdiDeviceCount; i++)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device Index: " + i.ToString());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Flags: " + String.Format("{0:x}", deviceInfos[i].Flags));
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Type: " + deviceInfos[i].Type.ToString());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + String.Format("{0:x}", deviceInfos[i].ID));
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Location ID: " + String.Format("{0:x}", deviceInfos[i].LocId));
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Serial Number: " + deviceInfos[i].SerialNumber.ToString());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Description: " + deviceInfos[i].Description.ToString());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");

                    serialNumbers.Add(deviceInfos[i].SerialNumber.ToString());
                }
            }

            return;
        }



        public void SetFifoMode()
        {
            FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus;
            ftStatus = ftHandle.OpenBySerialNumber(serialNumbers[1]);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot open device");
                return;
            }

            ftStatus = ftHandle.SetTimeouts(5000, 5000);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.SetBitMode(0xff, 0x00);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set bit mode");
                return;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.SetBitMode(0xff, 0x40);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set ftStatus");
                return;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.SetLatency(2);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set latency");
                return;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.InTransferSize(0x10000);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set In transfer size");
                return;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.SetFlowControl(FTDI.FT_FLOW_CONTROL.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS, 0, 0);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot set flow control");
                return;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            ftStatus = ftHandle.Purge(FTDI.FT_PURGE.FT_PURGE_RX);
            if (ftStatus != FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot purge FTDI");
                return;
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Synchronous FIFO mode enabled for " + serialNumbers[1]);


            // Create a task and supply a user delegate by using a lambda expression.
            Task taskA = new Task(() => ReceiveLoop());
            // Start the task.
            taskA.Start();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ReceiveLoop enabled");
        }


        public bool IsDeviceAllowed(string allowedDevice)
        {
            foreach (string device in serialNumbers)
            {
                if (device == allowedDevice)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Allowed device");
                    return true;
                }
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No allowed device");
            return false;
        }



        void ReadAvailable()
        {
            FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus;
            UInt32 numBytesAvailable = 0;

            ftStatus = ftHandle.GetRxBytesAvailable(ref numBytesAvailable);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ftStatus + "  bytes available: " + numBytesAvailable.ToString());

            if (numBytesAvailable < 1)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NO_READ_DATA_AVAILABLE\n");
                return;
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytesAvailable];
            UInt32 numBytesRead = 0;
            ftHandle.Read(bytes, numBytesAvailable, ref numBytesRead);
            if (numBytesAvailable != numBytesRead)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something bad happened");

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dec: " + String.Join(" ", bytes) + "\nHex: " + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty) + "\nText: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes) + "\n");

        }

        public void ReceiveLoop()
        {
            var receivedDataEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            ftHandle.SetEventNotification(FTDI.FT_EVENTS.FT_EVENT_RXCHAR, receivedDataEvent);

            //var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();  // should be declared in a broader scope
            //while (!_cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
            while (true)
            {
                receivedDataEvent.WaitOne();
                ReadAvailable();
            }
        }


        public void SaveRxDataToFile(byte[] rxData)
        {

            String filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_readout") + ".bin";

            const int dataLengthTotal = 1024000;
            int dataLength = 0;
            do
            {

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                {
                    fileStream.Write(rxData, dataLength, rxData.Length);
                }
                dataLength += rxData.Length;

            } while (dataLength < dataLengthTotal);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All the methods you've got there are "void", they don't return a result. Have you learned how to write methods that return a type?

Comment: The basic idea could be that `ReadAvailable()` could return... data buffer? But it is executed in `ReceiveLoop()` task fucnction so I don't know how to pass that data then to `SaveRxDataToFile()`.

Comment: You can store the results of a method call in a variable, and then pass that variable to another function. For example: `var myData = ReadAvailable(); SaveRxDataToFile(myData);` Of course that's very simplistic, and you'll need to think about what data types your methods should return. Avoid using private fields, as that makes it difficult to track the flow of information.

Comment: You code is wrong.  You have : if (numBytesAvailable != numBytesRead) and often the number of bytes read will not be the max or the last block will usually be less than the max size of the buffer.  The write to the file should be done in this section of the code.